# Firebase storage - "regardless of network quality"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Reading [Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) it says that

> Firebase Storage provides secure file uploads and downloads for your Firebase apps, **regardless of network quality**.

But I tried to start an upload without connection and then reconnecting, and it didn't work.

How do I enable offline capabilities for Firebase **Storage** ? (I already have `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true`)

Note: I'm implementing an app for iOS in Swift.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
FirebaseAPI.storageRef.child("images/test.jpg").putFile(imageURL)
```

Comment: Can you post the iOS code that you are using to upload?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it makes much difference,

Comment: We're also having this problem on iOS. If network is down or lost during upload it just errors out.

Comment: @TravisChristian my guess right now is that the Storage API does not support offline uploads. I was just hoping someone would come and prove me wrong =(